# How to mute system sounds in LXDE

Tags: audio, lxde

I used some guy's script to disable system beep. Now I am annoyed by sounds stored in `/usr/share/sounds/freedesktop/`. Zypper, however, told me that to get rid of them I would also need to uninstall notification-daemon, which I want to stay. Do I have to search for a replacement like `notify-osd` or is there a way to turn off warning dialog sounds in LXDE? The mixer sadly doesn't provide any "notification" or "system sounds" checkboxes, nor does YaST

Comment: If my only option is to do a dirty replace, can you tell me where can I get a blank .oga file so I rename it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Sound and Video- > Pulse Audio Volume Control
- Under Playback tab,
  make 'System Sounds' to zero